# Flux through arbitrary surface of known volume

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors, divergence-operator

We've been given a solid region E in $\mathbb{R}^3$, of known volume 10 cubic units.

Now, we're told to calculate the flux of a field $H =
\frac{−3}{(x^2+y^2+z^2)^{3/2}} \langle x, y, z \rangle$ through $\partial$E, assuming the origin lies inside E.

The hint given is use Gauss' Law. However, when I proceed to calculate the divergence, it equates to $0$, making the flux $0$. This, unfortunately, is incorrect, as the given answer is $-12\pi$.

Is my understanding of the question wrong?

Comment: How did you get the divergence is zero...? And are you given **what exaclty** the solid $\;E\;$ is? Because you can use Gauss Theorem only if the solid is bounded and closed (compact) , so being only "a solid region" can be insufficient.

Comment: Maybe there's a error in the answer? I got 0 for the divergence as well.

Comment: Sorry, we are given that the solid is bounded and closed.

Comment: Could it be that it's through $\partial E$ and not E?

Comment: Well, I got div equal to zero, too...

Comment: Maybe you looked at the answer of *another question* ? Did you take this question from a book, from  a site...?

Comment: It was from a practice exam. I've added a link to the exact question.

https://imgur.com/a/9ltuG

P.S. : What is the difference between integrating over surface E and $\partial E$ ?

Comment: For the the flux, being a surface integral, what's the relevance of its *volume* ...?

Comment: Well, it's only a matter of knowing whether that hint there is correct or not: as the origin lies inside $\;E\;$, it may well be the vector field isn't continuously differentiable there...maybe not even its partial derivatives of first order are continuous there, and thus Gauss Theorem cannot be applied here.

Comment: @gReaper FYI, in the link that you provided, the answer for question a) is wrong. Can you figure out which is the correct one?

Comment: @Kuifje Would it be none of these then? Also, could you please tell me where I could read more about the generalizations of the Gauss's Theorem?

Comment: The $x$ coordinate of the center of mass of solid is given by $\iiint_E x \rho(x,y,z) \; dV$ where $\rho$ is the density...Sorry I don't have any literature in mind for the generalization of the Gauss theorem, but for exam preparation: either you saw it in class - in this case, ask your professor-, either you did not - in this case don't worry about it!

Comment: Oh, but the question also says that the region is made of a material of constant density.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @DonAntonio, you cannot use the divergence/Gauss theorem here, because the vector field is not differentiable in $(0,0,0)$, which lies in $E$. You can however use a generalization of the theorem, which states that the flux equals
$$
\Phi = \iiint_E \nabla \cdot \vec{H}\; dV - \iint_S\vec{H}\cdot d\vec{S}
$$
where $S$ is any closed surface in which lies $(0,0,0)$, with an inward orientation. The first term equals $0$, and it is not hard to compute the second one with $S$ being a sphere with a "small" radius. You are going to have to use spherical coordinates, and the field $\vec{H}$ will be more simple to manage. In fact you will notice that the flux through a sphere does not depend on its radius here (the radius will vanish in the computations), leaving you with 
$$-3\iint_S \sin\phi \; d\theta d\phi = -3 \times 4\pi =-12 \pi$$

Comment: That helps! I was just wondering if you could provide me with some literature on the generalization that you used. Thanks!